# Code Completion with Ruby + Qt

Tags: ruby, qt, netbeans, ide

I'm currently learning Qt programming with Ruby.  Does anyone know an IDE that provides code completion for the Qt APIs when using Ruby?

I'm using NetBeans at the moment - I've set it up to use the standard Ruby interpreter as I didn't know how to get Qt working with JRuby - would getting this set up correctly solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Linux, you can try [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/) with the [Ruby plugin](http://websvn.kde.org/trunk/playground/devtools/kdevelop4-extra-plugins/). If there is one IDE supporting both Ruby and Qt, it's KDevelop.

If you are using Ubuntu, it is a bit of trouble because there is no .deb packages available for the Ruby plugin, you will have to build the plugin yourself.

There is some instructions to build the php plugin for Ubuntu here : http://milianw.de/blog/building-kdevplatform-kdevelop-and-the-php-plugin-from-svn. I suspect that the procedure should be almost the same for the ruby plugin.

Comment: I've tried following the Kdevelop instructions for compiling, but not had any success - if it's not available pre-compiled it's a but of a non-option for me, although if I don't get any other replies I will accept this as the answer since it seems to be the only solution available.